# Convert numerical character strings with multiple decimals to numeric data type in R

Tags: r, type-conversion

I have a variable with 8 million or so values in my data frame that are formatted like this: `1.275.900.0` (character data type). Changing them to factors is a no go because it slows down processing, so I need numerics.

I tried getting rid of the decimals and performing data type coercion with . . .

```
df$variable = as.numeric(sub(".", "", df$variable, fixed=TRUE))
```

Unfortunately, I got `Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion.`

How do I get around this?

Comment: Try `gsub` instead of `sub`

Comment: Well, I got the error again, but unlike prior attempts, it didn't NA out the entire vector. In fact, most everything appears to be here. There is one case the above would not catch, but it's trivial and would have been removed anyway.

Comment: I think you might have to escape the . because otherwise it is interpreted as a regular expression.

Comment: @TinglTanglBob This is not necessary because of the `fixed=TRUE` argument. The problem was `sub` which would replace only the first `.` in each element which is why I suggested `gsub`.

Comment: @markus, thanks for the info. Didn't know the fixed parameter before.

Comment: But what answer do you want? should 1.275.900.0 become 1.2759000 or 1275.9000 or 1275900.0  or 12759000?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [markus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8583393/markus) stated:

```
test<-"1.275.900.0"

as.numeric(gsub(".", "", test,fixed=T))
```

Should get you what you need.